# Extract the words used by a fuzzy query

Tags: elasticsearch

I use a fuzzy query in Elasticsearch and it works fine.

For example, if I search for *dogs* and the `_source` had the word *dog*
I get the correct document, but I don't know that the word *dog* was used for the result.

If `_source` had 10 000 words, how can I find that the query found `dog`?
Have you an idea to find the words scored into the result ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Please add more details.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english ....

Answer (score 0):

i find my solution by adding :
      "highlight": {
        "fields" : {
            "myfields" : {}
        }

I find the exact position of the hits

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood your question correctly but it looks like you might want to try highlighting.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

Comment: Thanks for you reply ! that ok !